# echarts - override time scale component

Tags: webpack, echarts

I would like to be able to modify / override the scale levels:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-echarts/blob/0711cdfb0f5d8809d106a34e2e16daad991cb9e1/src/scale/Time.js#L211

Specifically, I'd like to change 'year' to 'yyyy' either in Time.js or be able to override the formatTime function in format.js.

Is there any way to do this? 
I use webpack to build the lib, can I override the component that way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the formatTime function. Have this code run before the chart is initialized.

```
const echartsFormatTime = echarts.format.formatTime;
    echarts.format.formatTime = function formatTime(tpl, value, isUTC) {
        switch (tpl) {
            case 'dd/MM/yyyy':
                break;
            case 'year':
                tpl = 'yyyy';
                break;
            case 'MM-dd\nyyyy':
                tpl = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
                break;
            default:
                tpl = 'MM/yyyy';
        }
        return echartsFormatTime(tpl, value, isUTC);
    }
```